# how to filter contains full-text-search SharePoint online post query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

how to filter contains full-text-search SharePoint online post query

Example:

> search "software" in "program software"

Comment: Please indicate if the answer below works for you or clarify your question further so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you clear your question a little bit more.
Here I have used **substringof** to find contains text.
I think you want to filter where contains text is matched. Code looks like this:

```
sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle('ListName').items.select('Title,ISDNNumber')
  .filter(`substringof('${searchString}',Title) or substringof('${searchString}',ISDNNumber)`)
  .top(100).get()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.warn)
```

|